# Vectorization report call tree

Tags: c++, loops, optimization, vectorization

I am using `GCC7.2.0` and have a function as follows:

```cpp
auto sadd = [](auto & out, const auto & in, const double factor=1.)
{
  for (auto i=0u;i<in.size();++i) out[i]+=factor*in[i];
};
```

that I use everywhere throughout my code, mostly with `std::array` types.

I would like to know which calls to this lambda have been vectorized and which calls haven't.

Since the lambda is inlined, the vectorization report does not give me information on the call tree, so I don't know where vectorization succeeds and where it fails.

I use the flags `-std=c++1z -Ofast -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=9 -fopt-info-all=vec.info`.

Is there any way to obtain a vectorization report with a call tree that is readable, or should I just try to read the assembly?

Comment: That loop you have could be replaced by a call to [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform). Which since C++17 allows different [execution policies](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t).

Comment: You might use regular template function/functor to have more readable report.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for your comment. Using a template function/functor doesn't change the fact that the vectorization report does not show where the function has been called, or am I missing something?